# Username from hpyerlink

Tags: php, hyperlink, while-loop

I have got a `while` loop getting usernames from a SQL database.
Thanks

Comment: Becaue you have $user_id = $row['user_id']; inside the loop and so everytime $user_id changes. It stop changing when the loop ends. Thus, in the var you have always the last username fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong.
There is no use for the session here.
Only you heed is just a regular *hyperlink* which will pass the users *ID* to the next page. got the idea?

```
    echo "<tr></td><a href='viewallforms.php?id=$user_id'>$name</a></td></tr>';
```

and then you will have a user id in the viewallforms.php from `$_GET['id']` variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter to pass to other page using a view.php?name=value.
you want a solution in your way.check it.

```
<?php
if ($result) 
  {
    echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">"; 
    echo "<th><center>User ID</center></th>";
    echo "<th><center>Name</center></th>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $name = $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'];
                $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $user_id
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo '<form method="post" action="viewallforms.php">
    <input type="submit" value="' . $name . '"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sumbit" value="true"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="$user_id"/></form>'; 
        echo "</td></tr>";          
    }
  }
  echo "</table>";  

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  }
  else {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['userid'];           
    echo $user_id;
    }

  ?>
```